# Test javascript in node's public folder using jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a simple javascript function in an example.js file placed inside the node js public directory.
I am using jest for unit testing.
The problem is if I write the following in the example.js javascript file in the public folder:
**module.exports.myFunction = myFunction;** 
Jest test file is able to import it, using **require()** and perform tests, however when I run the web application, the browser complains when I service the page containing this javascript:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined**

**What is the correct way to test javascript files in the public directory of the node application?** 
Using export and/or import in the project is reported an being unrecognized and results in errors as well.

How is this done?

Comment: You're trying to test client-sode code? And the client-side code isn't being run throigh Webpack/Babel/etc?

Comment: That is correct. Thank you for your response. Is there a best practice I am not aware of?

Comment: There is no such thing, officially, as a node js public directory. Are you using a framework like Express or Next or something else?  Most frameworks which handle client-side code (try Next.js if you aren't using one) will bundle your code so that it can run correctly in browsers. In that case you shouldn't generally put things in the public folder, but instead serve up the build directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments `require(...)` and `module.exports` relate to [Common JS Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), which are natively supported by NodeJS runtime, but not by browser. So basically you'll need to add extra build configuration to have your module work in both runtimes.

If you want to have outputs in both CommonJs and Browser friendly bundle - you can write all code in [ES Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) and use build tools like webpack to provide outputs in different formats.

Also, [starting from Node 13.2.0](https://nodejs.medium.com/announcing-core-node-js-support-for-ecmascript-modules-c5d6dc29b663) - it supports ES modules natively. So I would stick to ES modules for ongoing development anyway.

Please also check [this short article](https://www.devguide.at/en/javascript/amd-cjs-umd-esm-modular-javascript/) on main JS module format differences.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I am indeed looking into webpack. Im currently using node 15.12.0 so will be looking into ES modules native support as well.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I am updated and have incorporated webpack 5 and babel. However, I noticed that babel is not transpiling arrow functions in my setup :(

Comment: Babel config is definitely a separate problem. You might miss some of presets in your config. Please raise another question with details on what browsers are you targeting and providing your current config. You can also mark this answer as accepted it it brings clarity to modules usage.

Comment: Agree babel and webpack configuration is another issue. I have preset @babel/env loaded and plugin as well and   plugins: [
                        "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions", {spec: true}
                      ]  Will try to locate what is amiss. If my efforts don't bear fruit, I will post it as a separate question. Thanks again. Your inputs are really appreciated.

Comment: Is that really the answer to the question? More tools, more steps, more everything? If you are in node repl and can load a file with .load, you should also be able to include it into another script, not?! Else, node is entirely useless for client side javascript file testing....

Comment: this is a trade off of using separate runtimes (nodejs/browser) for testing and running your code, you need to deal with the differences, yourself of using extra tooling

Comment: @SanketRajgarhia Webpack is very hard to configure yourself. If you are committed to not running a framework, which would generally handle the bundling (what Webpack does) for you, then try [Parcel](parceljs.org).

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with this some months ago and I wasn't able to find an accurate answer back then but I did understand that the issue is due to env being different in which we are running our code and testing our code. Extra tooling was not a solution accessible to me back then so I created this workaround for myself which is not the best but works.

```js
// Include this at the top of the public js file
if (typeof __funcs == 'undefined' || typeof __funcs != 'object') {
    var __funcs = {};
}

function one() {}

function two() {
    __funcs.one();
}

// Include this at the bottom of the public js file
try {
    if (typeof module != 'undefined') {
        // include the functions in here you want to export and test using  
        // Jest in Node env in an isolated manner
        module.exports = __funcs = {
            ...__funcs, one, two 
        };
    } else {
        // include functions in here for situations when you want to test 
        // calls to some other function  
        __funcs = { ...__funcs, one };
    }
} catch (ex) {
    console.error(`Error while exporting entities from [name of the file] script`, ex);
}
```

**Some important points:**

1. The double underscore is for indicative purposes. Its a convention of naming that indicates that the variable is sensitive/internal and should be carefully used or accessed and prevent accidental change or overriding.
2. The use of **var** here adds on to the negatives of this approach. You can get rid of it but you will have to make trade offs and come up with alternatives if you want to cover good amount and paths in test cases.
3. I think you may be able to get rid of var by devising a way to setup an internal naming mechanism where each public js file you want to write test cases for has its own separate version of __funcs. This would however make it complicated for you to write test cases where calls to functions in a separate file are done. This is the entire reason I doubt I used var for and the purpose of the code we are including at the top of the file. I thought __funcs should not get overwritten and we wont have to declare separate variable for each of the files, __funcs will be universal.
4. If you want to write isolated test cases and thus don't require funcs, you can eliminate the need of var altogether. In this case, you simply export the things you want to test with the code inside the if conditon inside try-catch.
5. I think you can even achieve what funcs is doing by directly declaring external functions you want to test that are called from inside the function you are testing, on the globals variable in the test file. You will have to try and see.